# Nexus 7 Freezes on lockscreen on Ubuntu Touch Preview

Tags: ubuntu-touch

So I just finished flashing today's new Ubuntu Touch Preview to my WiFi-only Nexus 7 (nakasi), however it freezes at the lockscreen and refuses to let me get any further. The clock moves, & I'm able to lock/unlock the tablet, but everything else appears to be frozen.

Any advice? Should I just flash Android 4.2.2 back on it & try again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

same happened to me. swipe left to right from the extreme left edge of the screen. you should see the application bar appear from left.

Comment: Ah, thank you so much! Can't believe I didn't notice this at first; it works now. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The actual way to unlock it seems to be swiping from the right edge to the left.
That returns you to the most recent screen/app you were on.